# Finding the final temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, heat

If $125$ Calories of heat is applied to $60.0\text{g}$ piece of copper at $21.0^\circ\text{C}$, what will the final temperature be? The specific head of copper is $0.0920 \text{ cal/gC}$.

All I have to answer this question is a formula:

$SH = \text{heat/(mass}\times \Delta T)$

Comment: Please see http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange for how to ask homework questions.  Please outline what you have attempted towards solving the problem.

Comment: Any hint would be great. I'm really not sure how to go about the answer. I've been working on it for about 3 hours already, as silly as it sounds.

Comment: I understand that asking homework questions here will erode the quality of this site. I wrote anyways as a last resort. Any hints on how to go about the answer would be great. Anyone else looking for the answer can see your hints and benefit as well.

Comment: Rather than just us being draconian, it is helpful for those answering to see what your thought process is so they can steer you in the right direction.  What else do you know about the problem?  Do you have a formula in mind, if so, do the dimensions work out?

Comment: Split $\Delta T$ up into $T_f - T_i$, and you have all of the rest of the parameters.

Comment: Ohhh.. ok great that makes thinges easier!

Comment: And now, post your answer below so the next student finds your method instead of having to ask another question ;)

Comment: Oh, :/ I'm a bit embarrassed because I don't remember it. I just submitted my assingment. I can see why homework isn't allowed. I appreciate the help though! 

I remember plugging all the numbers into the equation and then solving for Tf, or the final time. So I multiplied the denom by both sides, and I think I had to do some unit conversions. It's simply algebra from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy amount used for heating up a material can be calculated according to the following equation:
$$ E = c_\text{s}\, m\, \Delta T$$
where $E$ is the energy, $c_\text{s}$ the specific heat capacity, $m$ the mass of the object and $\Delta T$ the temperature difference that is to be achieved.

Solving the above equation for $\Delta T$ we get:
$$ \Delta T = \frac{E}{c_\text{s}\, m}$$

Plugging in the values provided by you, I get $\Delta T = 22.6\;\mathrm{K}$ (or °C, since we're talking about the *difference* and the scale is the same, it doesn't matter).

Adding this increase in temperature to the initial temperature gives the final answer:
$$ \vartheta_\text{f} = \vartheta_\text{i} + \Delta \vartheta = 21.0\; \mathrm{°C} + 22.6\; \mathrm{°C} = 43.6\; \mathrm{°C}$$

Note the following:

- **Number of significant digits:** Since the data given consistently had three significant digits, I've rounded to the third digit.
- **Symbol for temperature:** I used $\vartheta$ for temperatures in °C and $T$ for temperatures in K. I strongly suggest you follow this example as to never confuse the two.